# How do I send a large amount of text into a contenteditable="true" element?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, puppeteer, contenteditable

UPDATE:

After some more research, I realized I can ask this question in a more specific manner: How do I send a large amount of text into a `contenteditable="true"` element?

---

I am working with a website that has an API but it doesn't have any endpoints that can edit content. This API limitation prevents my release process from being automated. As a workaround, I've tried to automate the tasks with a headless browser.

One of these tasks involves editing the content in a rich text editor. This rich text editor does not have any `input` elements, so this isn't as simple as changing the value of something. The HTML looks similar to this:

[image]

You can look at the source of this rich text editor here: https://www.slatejs.org/examples/richtext

I've tried using some puppeteer code (I don't care if the solution to this answer is puppeteer or not) to solve this problem. It works, but it's far too slow: I've got 30k of text to send to the editor, so `await page.keyboard.type(stdin, {delay: 0});` takes well over ten minutes to run. Here is my code:

```js
export const edit = async () => {
  const browser = await launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  try {
    await page.setUserAgent(
      'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:93.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0'
    );
    await page.goto('https://www.slatejs.org/examples/richtext');
    await page.waitForSelector('[data-slate-string="true"]');
    await page.click('[data-slate-string="true"]');
 
    // select all
    await page.keyboard.down('Control');
    await page.keyboard.press('a');
    await page.keyboard.up('Control');

    // clear everything in the rich text editor
    await page.keyboard.press('Backspace');

    // type in new content
    await page.keyboard.type(aLargeAmountOfText, {delay: 0}); // this takes over 10 minutes!  
  } finally {
    await page.screenshot({ path: 'example.png' });
    await browser.close();
  }
};
```

One thing that *would* work (in theory), is to automate copying and pasting the text into the editor. I really don't want to go down this path, because I tend to do other things while I release. If my script modifies my clipboard (or I modify it) while it's running, it could have unpredictable results.

What's the quickest way of sending a large amount of text to a rich text editor that has no `input` elements? I don't care what automation tool is used (I'd prefer node.js, if possible), or what tricks I have to use, so long as I can figure out how to answer this question.

Comment: You could automate copy and pasting, but then revert to the prior clipboard contents as soon as the paste command runs, so it'll have no discernable effect on whatever else you're doing on the computer at that time. For Windows, AutoHotkey could also help.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I do happen to be using Windows for this, but I don't know how to get the clipboard content into a variable before I override it. I'd prefer that over installing this tool.

Comment: @CertainPerformance In addition, it feels like my concern could still occur under certain circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this was *so* hard to figure out. Here it is:

```js
    await page.goto(url);

    const richTextEditorSelector = '[contenteditable="true"]';
    await page.waitForSelector(richTextEditorSelector);
    await page.focus(richTextEditorSelector);

    // select all
    await page.evaluate(() => {
      return Promise.resolve(document.execCommand('selectAll'));
    });

    const pasteReplacementText = `
const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();

function dispatchPaste(target) {
  // this may be 'text/html' if it's required
  dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', \`${replacementText}\`);

  target.dispatchEvent(
    new ClipboardEvent('paste', {
      clipboardData: dataTransfer,

      // need these for the event to reach Draft paste handler
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: true
    })
  );

  // clear DataTransfer Data
  dataTransfer.clearData();
}

dispatchPaste(document.querySelectorAll('${richTextEditorSelector}')[0]);
`;

    console.log(`replacementText=

${pasteReplacementText}`); // leaving this here because it may help others troubleshoot
    await page.evaluate(pasteReplacementText);
```

That complex string tricks the editor into thinking a paste occurred. You supply the data.

Here are some of the sources I used to come up with this:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63643176/61624
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content
3. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent
4. https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args
5. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand

Answer (score 1):

```
let input1 = '#abc'
let target = 'something'

await page.waitForSelector(input1)
await page.focus(input1)
await page.$eval(input1, (el, value) => el.textContent = value, target);
await page.keyboard.press('\n');
```

Sometimes directly pouring data into nodes won't kick off the processes that are expecting some key inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You might try it with [page.$eval](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v10.4.0&show=api-pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1):

```
export const edit = async () => {
  const browser = await launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  try {
    await page.setUserAgent(
      'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:93.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0'
    );
    await page.goto('https://www.slatejs.org/examples/richtext');
    await page.waitForSelector('[contenteditable="true"]');
    await page.$eval('[contenteditable="true"]', (e) => e.textContent = aLargeAmountOfText);
  } finally {
    await page.screenshot({ path: 'example.png' });
    await browser.close();
  }
};
```

Comment: I keep getting errors about how `aLargeAmountOfText` isn't defined. I thought I already figured how to solve this (by passing it in as the last argument to `$eval`), but even when i do, I get the same error. code=`await page.$eval('[contenteditable="true"]', (e) => (e.textContent = replacementText), replacementText);` error=`Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: replacementText is not defined`

Comment: I have doubts that will work anyway. At least, I don't think the output will look like it would be if I type/pasted that same text into the editor.