# Why my Paste event does not work on few sites?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, range, selection

I am trying to programmatically insert strings into text fields. I tried `document.execCommand("insertText", false, wordToInsert);` But it does not work on few sites which are using draft.js editor e.g Facebook. Sometimes it behaves unexpectedly e.g after inserting the text, backspace or enter key doesn't work. So after researching [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54256517/insert-text-into-an-existing-external-draftjs-textfield), I ended up with a solution of dispatching a paste event as shown in the code snippets below.

```js
const target = document.querySelector('[contenteditable="true"]');

target.addEventListener('paste', (event) => {
  console.log('Paste event caught!');
  console.log('Clipboard data:', event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain'));
});

const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'hello');
target.dispatchEvent(
  new ClipboardEvent('paste', {
    clipboardData: dataTransfer,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
  })
);

dataTransfer.clearData();
```

Now above code works on draft.js demo [site](https://draftjs.org/) but does not work on my simple [test site](https://aianytime.azurewebsites.net/test.html). You can test this code by simply opening those sites and pasting it on the console.

Note: I am looking for a simple universal insertText function that can work on any site's input, textarea or content-editable fields.

Comment: Why not just assign to `element.value`?

Comment: assigning value does not work on few sites like twitter

Comment: So first assign the value. If that doesn't work, use this.

Comment: how do you detect when assigning value does not work?

Comment: Check if the value has changed.

Comment: Sometimes, value changed successfully but it works unexpectedly after that. E.g Enter or Backspace event does not work.